# node.js express mongodb save messages?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I'm trying to see express, mongoose and MongoDB work together, in a really simple way. If I can have a box, put my name in there, submit it and have it save to the DB, that's all I need.

I tried doing this from taking pieces of tutorials but I'm stuck. I was trying to do it through a chat and just save every message. If you can get my example to work or have one of your own, either way, It just helps me see something that works.

Then I can have a foundation of what works and can add to it. I see a lot of tutorials and everything else, but not something simple for people, it's always a big project you get lost on somewhere, hopefully, this will be helpful to others too, it's a lot, with everything, with node and all its friends.

With my example, I am not getting any errors, that I see, but there may be some. And I'm looking in DB chat to see the messages using db.messages.find() but there not in there.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
        <style>
            #chat{
                height:500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat"></div>
        <form id="send-message">
            <input size="35" id="message"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var socket = io.connect();
                var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
                var $messageBox = $('#message');
                var $chat = $('#chat');
       
                $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                    $messageBox.val('');
                });
       
                socket.on('new message', function(data){
                    $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
                });
            });

            var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
                msg: String,
                created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
            });

            var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);

            var newMsg = new Chat({msg: msg});
            newMsg.save(function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
            });               


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chat', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code?

Comment: @JohnnyHK sorry don't know how.

Comment: Insert spaces to indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried it and the modified version bellow works! The main changes where putting the mongoose schema code on the server side, and echo back the content of the text box on the server only after a successful save in the Mongo database.

Have a look also at the [mean.io](http://mean.io) site for introduction to the MEAN stack, let me know if you have questions on the code.

Modified server.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){

        var newMsg = new Chat({msg: '' + data});

        console.log('saving newMsg: ' + newMsg);

        newMsg.save(function(err){
            console.log('saved, err = ' + err);
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('echoeing back data =' + data);
            io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
        });

    });
});

var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    msg: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);



mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err){
if(err){
console.log(err);
} else{
    console.log('Connected to mongodb!');
}
});
```

This is the html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
        <style>
            #chat{
                height:500px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat"></div>

        <form id="send-message">
            <input size="35" id="message"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var socket = io.connect();
                var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
                var $messageBox = $('#message');
                var $chat = $('#chat');

                $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                    $messageBox.val('');
                });

                socket.on('new message', function(data){
                    console.log('Received data: ' + data);
                    $chat.append(data + "<br/>");
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ty! I'm using chat db and tried db.messages.find() and nothings in there?

Comment: I changed the database to test in the code above instead of the chat database. do use test; and then db.messages.find(), the messages should be there.

Comment: I have mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test instead of mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chat in my code above

Comment: @ jhadesdev im in the test db and using db.messages.find() inside mongo and i don't see anything.

Comment: I also renamed the html page to test.html, did you change that back to index? post the results of the console in the server and in the client I have added console.log statements as well, can you post those as well. This is working in node and chrome, do you have some error messages?

Comment: I mean res.sendfile(__dirname + '/test.html');, did you change it back to index.html to make sure the correct version of the page is being used, try Ctrl + F5, right click and inspect element on Chrome to confirm it's the new HTML