# Create Mongoose collection on Express

Tags: database, mongodb, sockets, express, mongoose

On app.js, I have this:

```
let Gamestat = require('./models/gamestat');

mongoose.connect(config.database, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
let db = mongoose.connection;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
(...)

    socket.on('gameEnded', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('gameEnd', data);
        //add game stats to database
        let newStat = new Gamestat({
          time: 'testing',
          winner: 'testing',
          loser: 'testing',
          moves: 'testing'
        });
    });
});
```

/config/database.js:

```
module.exports = {
  database: 'mongodb://localhost/nodekb',
  secret: ''
}
```

This last part of app.js, where I create gameStatm is executed, but when I type "show collections" on cmd, it doesn't show this collection (although it shows the others). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call newStat.save(function(err){ ... }) to save the data. [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928028/9626566) I found ...